# What is the meaning of the following cartoon?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the following cartoon?

[image]

I have a few questions in this regard:

1. Is it mentioning "siamese twins"?
2. Why are the people wearing shabby/torn clothes?

Comment: Siamese is a breed of cat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_cat

Comment: @Katy, Yes, but what does this entire cartoon point at?

Comment: On first interpretation, it looked pretty much like nonsense to me, but after considering it, I think the intention is that the cat has scratched up the couple, and the "joke" is that even though she sees that, the other woman still asks if the cat is friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "Siamese" is a breed of cat.  It is implied that the cat has scratched and injured the man and woman, as well as torn their clothing.  The joke is that it is obvious that the cat is not friendly, or is not friendly to the man and woman, but she asks anyway.

Alternatively, it also calls to mind situations in which an abuser presents a "friendly face" to outsiders while doing horrible things to those close to them... but then applies that situation to a cat instead of to people.  The change in context is amusing.